# How to Change Document Size with Click in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

Is it possible to change the windows/document size in jQuery by clicking on a button? For example I am trying to do some thing like this:

```
<button type="button" class="mobile">Mobile size!</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".mobile").click(function () {
    $(document).height() = "400px";
    $(document).width() = "300px";
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First answer, no not really. There is a reason why there aren't any native methods to specifically resize the window. You can attach resize handlers to your window, detect the change, and respond in kind.

Why would you want to change the actual window or browser size? That is a decision left to the client and your code should respond to their browsers/viewing device.

You could also use media queries to render a mobile style sheet based off of window size.